# Google Cloud SDK installation - gsutil error

Tags: gcloud, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

I have installed Google Cloud SDK but having an issue running "gsutil". Here are the error I'm getting:

```
~/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk@> gsutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gonyi/Desktop/gonyyi/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 13, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/Users/gonyi/Desktop/gonyyi/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 40, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import execution_utils
  File "/Users/gonyi/Desktop/gonyyi/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/execution_utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import log
  File "/Users/gonyi/Desktop/gonyyi/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 810, in <module>
    _log_manager = _LogManager()
  File "/Users/gonyi/Desktop/gonyyi/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 526, in __init__
    self._file_formatter = _LogFileFormatter()
  File "/Users/gonyi/Desktop/gonyyi/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 315, in __init__
    super(_LogFileFormatter, self).__init__(fmt=_LogFileFormatter.FORMAT)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
~/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk@>
```

I have Python 2.7 installed, also tried to install this with "brew cask" as well as download it directly from Google Cloud site and install, but no luck either.

I googled this error but it seems like I'm the only one with this error..

"gcloud" command works just fine; but it's just "gsutil" that's not working.

Thank you

Comment: It seems like not only from "gsutil" but bq as well. (so bootstrapping)

Comment: The error indicates that _LogFileFormatter may be an old style class (not derived from object), which means logging.Formatter is an old style class. Very strange. It could be a Python installation issue, maybe gsutil picking up a different python. Run this "bash -x gsutil --version" and look at the last line of the bash trace, it shows what python was used to run gsutil.py.